# Заблокированные незакрытые вопросы с невысокой оценкой

Tags: обсуждение, заблокированные-вопросы

Есть [несколько вопросов с невысокой оценкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3A0%20locked%3A1%20score%3A..3), которые заблокированы, но при этом не являются закрытыми.

- [NullReferenceException - передается нулевой объект](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/515053)
- [Подсчет полного дохода подкомпаний TreeView](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526170)
- [java - Возможно ли обратиться к абстрактному методу абстрактного интерфейса, используя reflect?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/576428)

Из-за блокировки их нельзя удалить и даже голосовать по ним. Судя по всему эти блокировки должны были носить временный характер, но почему-то затянулись.

Предлагаю разобраться, что делать с такими вопросами.

Comment: Второй вроде объединён с чем-то?

Comment: разблокировал 1 и 3. Первый всё равно скоро удалит Дух.

Comment: @Qwertiy тогда я не понимаю смысла объединения. Всегда считал, что после объединения вопрос должен быть один, а иначе - это дубликаты.

Comment: @NickVolynkin на полноценный ответ по теме не готовы еще? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ситуация с вопросами успешно разрешилась.

В общем случае, если обычная (не историческая) блокировка висит на вопросе слишком долго, имеет смысл отметить такой вопрос тревогой для уведомления модератора о необходимости пересмотреть факт наличия блокировки.

О том, как следует объединять вопросы можно ознакомиться в [ответе на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96532/339911).